# Can we change the font color the network error pop-up to make it more readable?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comment-flags, popups

I happened to mistakenly hit the flag option on a comment. That time, due to some temporary network error I got an error pop-up. The font color in that error pop-up was hardly visible because of the background color. So can we change the font color or may be the background color so that the error message in the pop-up is easily readable? I know its a very minor request, but I feel it could be a very simple to implement too.

Here is a snapshot of that pop-up.

[image: Unreadable pop-up]

I'm using Firefox 26.0 on Win7 Pro, btw.

---

*Note:* Reading the comment from [Christmas Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211779/can-we-change-the-font-color-the-network-error-pop-up-to-make-it-more-readable#comment681113_211779), it seems that this might be a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). I'll keep this tagged as `bug` unless there is more clarification on it and will change it accordinly later.

Comment: That must be a bug!!!!. I get a different error pop-up that is readable

Comment: Right now they just throw inside the container the output of [such GET request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/flags/comments/681113/popup), probably need to also check status code.

Comment: That's not us, we don't have that phone number on any error page like that at any point in our pipe.  It looks like you're behind a proxy which it's own content into your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're getting error content from...well, *not us*.  That error message and phone number isn't something we would send from anything in our network.  *Something* is inbetween you and us putting that content there, a proxy.

See who's messing with your traffic there, or (hopefully in the coming year) start using HTTPS as we get the mixed content eliminated and stop an untrusted proxy from interfering.